# Await is not pausing execution

Tags: node.js, async-await, fastify

I can't figure out why execution continues, and await isn't pausing execution until the called function returns.

In a node.js application

Contacts.js

```
async function routes (fastify, options) {
    fastify.get('/contact', async (req, reply) => {
        let lookup = require('../helpers/validate_school');
        let school_info = await lookup.validate(req.hostname.split('.')[0]);
        console.log('here: ', school_info);
        let school = school_info.school;
        ...
        reply.view('application/application.html', school);
    });
};
```

school.lookup.js

```
async function validate(hostname){
    const con = require('../../config/db').getDb();
    let ret = {};
    console.log('lets check for school info');
    await con.query('SELECT * FROM schools where identifier=? LIMIT ?', [hostname, 1], function(err, res, fields){
        if (err) throw err;
        if (res.length > 0){
            ret.school = JSON.stringify(res[0]);
            ...
            console.log('found: ', ret);
            return ret;
        } else {
            console.log('not found: ', ret);
            return ret;
        }
    });
};
module.exports = {validate: validate};
```

log

```
lets check for school info
here:  undefined
found:  {
  school: '{"id":2,"name":"Second School","school_dbid":"2","primary_color":"purple","secondary_color":"lavender","tertiary_color":"green","quaternary_color":"blue","identifier":"school2","mascot_id":1,"created_at":"2019-11-20T05:22:16.864Z","updated_at":"2019-11-21T17:59:11.956Z"}',
  ...
}
```

How can I ensure that lookup.validate returns before proceeding in the code block?

Comment: You never use `return` within `validate`, so you'd always get `undefined` as a result.

Comment: Also, are you sure `con.query` returns a Promise?

Comment: Do NOT mix plain callbacks, `async` function declarations and promises.  Flow control is a disaster.  Promisify ALL your async operations and then use only promises for flow control.  Further `await con.query()` does NOTHING useful as that doesn't return a promise because you're using the callback interface with it, not the promise interface.  `await` does NOTHING useful except when you are awaiting a promise.  This needs a complete redesign, not one simple fix.

Comment: Basically, NEVER use plain asynchronous callbacks inside an `async` function.  Your `async` function won't work properly because the promise that it returns will NOT be linked to your asynchronous operations so the caller will have no way of knowing when they are done.

Comment: I would suggest you start by moving to `mysql2` which has a built-in promise interface.  Use ONLY the promise interface for all database related calls.  Then, you can use `await` on any database call and everything will be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire point of `await` is so that you do not have to use the callback. Instead it will just return the data to you or throw an error on reject. You need to pick one, either use just the callback or just async/await.

That being said, async/await only works on promises. But the `mysql` library does not use promises. So you can't even use async/await in this situation anyway, if you are using `mysql` and not `mysql2`.

Plus, callbacks will not return anything. Return statements do not work in asynchronous scenarios.

You have two options. Deal with the asynchronicity of the callback and use the value directly:

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM schools where identifier=? LIMIT ?', [hostname, 1], function(err, res, fields){
    // The result cannot leave this callback.
    // Anything you need to do with the result must be done here.
});
```

Or if you are using `mysql2` you can use a promise like this:

```
const data = await con.promise().query('your query');
```

Comment: All databases these days offer a promise interface.  The OP should use the promise interface to their database, not promisify `con.query()` themselves.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah, my bad. `mysql` does not support promises out of the box but `mysql2` does. Depends on which one OP is using.

Comment: Yep, `mysql2` is the way to go.

Comment: mysql2 FTW.  Thanks!